# How to create a Gdk.Pixbuf from a Unicode filename in Windows?

Tags: windows, unicode, mono, gtk, filenames

I have a C# / Mono / Gtk# program that simply loads files dropped in the window as Gdk.Pixbuf and displays them.

It works well on Ubuntu. But on Windows if I try to drop a file with a non-ASCII filename such as C:\áéíóú.jpg, the program will crash. I thought it was a problem with my code first. So I did a simple testcase.

```
Console.WriteLine("{0} exists? {1}", Filename, File.Exists(Filename));
Pixbuf pixels = new Pixbuf (Filename)
```

Output

> C:\áéíóú.jpg exists? True
>   GLib.GException: Failed to open file 'C:\áéíóú.jpg': No such file or directory

As it turns out, Glib can't figure out a file that exists, exists. And I don't know how to fix it so that I can load an image file into Pixbuf on windows from a Unicode filename.

Comment: Are you sure the filename string is in UTF8 encoding and the on-disk filename encoding is also UTF8?

Comment: I am not sure about that. When I was implementing drag'n'drop I read Gtk+ always use UTF-16 for encoding. So I encode the data I receive from drag'n'drop as UTF-16. However if I pass the filenames as a command-line argument, or through a Gtk file open dialog, I get the same result. Which is weird if you think a filename you get through Gtk isn't valid for Gdk.

Comment: GTK never uses UTF-16 for encoding. You must have read wrong. GLib uses UTF8 internally except for the encoding for filenames, which is UTF8 anyway on Windows, and even usually UTF8 on modern Unix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a problem in the gtk-sharp<->gdk-pixbuf interoperation.

Apparently on every OS except windows, `gdk_pixbuf_new_from_file` takes file name encoded in utf8. On windows, however, this function is renamed to `gdk_pixbuf_new_from_file_utf8` and replaced by a wrapper that does locale conversion and proceeds to call the utf8 version. gtk-sharp doesn't know this and uses `gdk_pixbuf_new_from_file` passing utf8 argument, hence the unexpected extra locale conversion on windows breaks the filename.

As a workaround I have suggested to use the `Pixbuf` constructor that takes a `Stream` instead of a filename, but the poster has reported that doesn't load his image properly.

**Update:**
Luckily the Pixbuf wrapper class has a constructor that accepts the raw IntPtr of an existing pixbuf object. As such, the code in the buggy constructor can be duplicated, fixed and hidden in some helper methods, such as:

```
[DllImport("libgdk_pixbuf-2.0-0.dll")]
static extern IntPtr gdk_pixbuf_new_from_file_utf8(IntPtr filename, out IntPtr error);

static Pixbuf CreatePixbufWin32(string filename)
{
    IntPtr native_filename = GLib.Marshaller.StringToPtrGStrdup(filename);
    IntPtr error = IntPtr.Zero;
    IntPtr raw = gdk_pixbuf_new_from_file_utf8(native_filename, out error);
    GLib.Marshaller.Free(native_filename);
    if (error != IntPtr.Zero) throw new GLib.GException(error);
    return new Pixbuf(raw);
}

static Pixbuf CreatePixbuf(string filename)
{
    if (Environment.OSVersion.Platform == PlatformID.Win32NT)
    {
        return CreatePixbufWin32(filename);
    }
    return new Pixbuf(filename);
}
```

I have tested this with success. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! That solved the problem. I hope Gtk# gets a similar function as part of the library one day.